# How to use DirectX.DirectInput in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, directx, joystick, xna-3.0

joystick.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput;

namespace gameproject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of device.
    /// </summary>
    class joysticks
    {

        public static Device joystick;
        public static JoystickState state;

        public static void InitDevices() //Function of initialize device
        {
            //create joystick device.
            foreach (DeviceInstance di in Manager.GetDevices(
                DeviceClass.GameControl,
                EnumDevicesFlags.AttachedOnly))
            {
                joystick = new Device(di.InstanceGuid);
                break;
            }

            if (joystick == null)
            {
                //Throw exception if joystick not found.
            }

            //Set joystick axis ranges.
            else {
                foreach (DeviceObjectInstance doi in joystick.Objects)
                {
                    if ((doi.ObjectId & (int)DeviceObjectTypeFlags.Axis) != 0)
                    {
                        joystick.Properties.SetRange(
                            ParameterHow.ById,
                            doi.ObjectId,
                            new InputRange(-5000, 5000));
                    }

                }

                joystick.Properties.AxisModeAbsolute = true;
                joystick.SetCooperativeLevel(null,CooperativeLevelFlags.NonExclusive | CooperativeLevelFlags.Background);

                //Acquire devices for capturing.
                joystick.Acquire();
                state = joystick.CurrentJoystickState;
            }
        }

        public static void UpdateJoystick()   // Capturing from device joystick
        {
            //Get Joystick State.
            if(joystick!=null)
                state = joystick.CurrentJoystickState;
        }

    }
}
```

**In this line, an error occurred,**

```
    joystick.SetCooperativeLevel(null,CooperativeLevelFlags.NonExclusive 
| CooperativeLevelFlags.Background);
```

**error,**

```
Error 1 The type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' is defined in an 
assembly that is not referenced.
     You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows.Forms...
```

I'm working on,XNA 3.0 and .NET 3.5, so what means that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetCooperativeLevel` takes `System.Windows.Forms.Control` object as a first parameter (where you have null), so you should still reference assembly where this class is defined in your application. Add reference do System.Windows.Forms.dll from your app/game and try then. If code you are using is using some other classes that you haven't referenced under the hood, it's ok, but when they are public (like they are parameter or are returned from methods you are calling), you have to reference assemblies in which those types are defined.

Similar stackoverflow post:
[Debugging error "The Type 'xx' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728562/debugging-error-the-type-xx-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced)