# Error Message when Referencing .dll Files

Tags: c#, reference, xna, directx, directinput

I would like the use DirectInput in my XNA game however I'm having an issue when it comes to referencing the .dll file. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio C# Express Edition. This is exactly what I do:

- right click "References"
- chose "add reference"
- navigate to the .dll file and hit OK

I then receive the following error:
[image]

As stated above I would like to reference the Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput namespace but I don't know which .dll file that it's in so I just picked the "d3dref9.dll". Every .dll file under that directory doesn't work though so any one I pick gives me the same error. Now I've been able to accomplish this with other .dll files but for some reason the DirectX ones wont work. I know it's possible beacuse [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604492/how-to-use-directx-directinput-in-xna) guy did it just look at the second line in his code.

I have the DirectX SDK installed why can't I reference any of the .dll files and how can I make it so I can?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are native DLLs. You need to find the managed ones. It should be named something like "Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.dll"

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are adding a reference to a native DLL while managed projects only support managed DLLS.  I believe the DLL you are looking for is `Microsoft.DirectX.dll`.  That has the managed wrappers for DirectX

Comment: Where would the location of "Microsoft.DirectX.dll" be? I have the latest DirectX SDK release for June 2010 http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6812

Comment: @MrSplosion I'm not exactly sure. The fastest way to find it though would be to search for `Microsoft.DirectX.dll` from the root SDK directory.  If it's not there then I would try the .Net SDK folder as it may install the DLL there

Comment: @MrSplosion looks like from this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vssetup/thread/563fcf70-ba0d-4a84-9ebb-10801075a06d they'll be in the ".\Developer Runtime\x86\DirectX for Managed Code" folder under the root SDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to reference .dlls that are not .NET assemblies, and/or not COM libraries.

[This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/gametechnologiesdirectx101/thread/88311c18-cad6-4279-9a24-9728ddd8fba2/) might help with locating the propper .dlls:

*(copy/paste from linked post:)*

> What you need to do is add the correct DLLs as references to your
>   project. Since they are not in the list, you'll have to add them
>   manually. I am assuming you are using the October SDK?
>
> What you'll need to do is:
>
> 1. Right-click on References folder, and select "Add Reference..."
> 2. On the .NET tab, select the "Browse" button.
> 3. Navigate to where you installed the SDK. (On my machine it is C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX 9.0 SDK)
> 4. The files you are looking for should be in ".\Developer Runtime\x86\DirectX for Managed Code"
> 5. Select the DLLs that you want (in this case Microsoft.DirectX.dll, Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.dll)

Comment: I have the June 2010 version from here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6812 I think that is the most up to date one. The only October release I found was from 2008. Why would I install that when June 2010 is the most up to date? I ask because using my version the "DirectX for Managed Code" directory isn't there and I can't find it.

Comment: Maybe they have changed the directory layout since then. Have you tried searching your drive for "Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.dll"?